# How do I pass element of static array to non static method?

Tags: c#, static

I have a static array and I need to pass an arbitrary element of it to a non-static method.

How do I do that?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int[] staticArray = { 3, 11, 43, 683, 2731 };

    public void SomeMethod(int value)
    {
        //...stuff...
    }

    public static void staticMethod()
    {
         SomeMethod(staticArray[2]);    //error here
    }
}
```

When I try something like that I get the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property`.

Comment: The above code compile (if you replace `...stuff...` with `//  ...stuff...`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in LinqPad.  You must have simplified your test too much.

Comment: That code compiled perfectly fine.. paste the rest of it.. the error must be somewhere else in ...stuff.... or somewhere...

Comment: Runs fine for me used a breakpoint and `43` was in value as expected.

Comment: @Albin, the OP did not have trouble compiling.

Comment: Paste the ....stuff code... as well. It compliled with no errors.

Comment: I'm betting that davecove's calling of `SomeMethod` is in fact _not_ from a class instance constructor but actually from a `static` method/constructor.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 - compliled correctly, no errors, everythings works.

Comment: Compiled and executes without issue.

Comment: @Chris, you are exactly right, I have edited it to be more correct. How can I do what I need without the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code as it is is fine, however `'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property'` occurs when you try to call `instance` method, or access a non-static field/property on something other than an instance of a class, say from a static method.  For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int imNotStatic;

    public static void Bar()
    {
        // This will give you your 'An object reference is required` compile 
        // error, since you are trying to call the instance method SomeMethod
        // from a static method, as there is no 'this' to call SomeMethod on.
        SomeMethod(5);

        // This will also give you that error, as you are calling SomeMethod as
        // if it were a static method.
        MyClass.SomeMethod(42);

        // Again, same error, there is no 'this' to read imNotStatic from.
        imNotStatic = -1;
    }

    public void SomeMethod(int x)
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Ensure that you are not doing one of the above.  Are you sure you are calling `SomeMethod` from a constructor?

Comment: I appear to be doing exactly that...  plz see my edited original post.  So, how can I do what I need without the error?  Dave

Comment: You can't, `SomeMethod` would need to be static for you to call it from a static method.  Please refresh on the difference between static and instance methods, and hopefully that should give you insight into the correct way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: However, note that from within `SomeMethod`, you would have access to `staticArray`, which means instead of `// stuff` you could write `int value = staticArray[2];`

Comment: but if I can't call `SomeMethod` from `staticMethod` I can't get to `int value = staticArray[2];` when another form calls `staticMethod`.  The aim here is to allow other forms in the app to use `MyClass.staticMethod();` to run `SomeMethod` which does stuff to `MyClass` via non-static props/methods.

Comment: That aim implies a misunderstanding of how `static` and `instances` differ.  Say in your program you had `MyClass a;  MyClass b;`  When you call `MyClass.staticMethod();` what instance would it call `SomeMethod` on?  a, b?  From within a static method *there is no instance of MyClass to call non-static props/methods on*

Comment: "That aim implies a misunderstanding of how static and instances differ." Guilty as charged...  in my head `static` basically meant 'available simply by referencing the class'. Obviously it is a lot more involved that that. I typically use static properties and rarely static methods. My use of static props is limited to 'publishing' certain props of a Form derived class so that other forms in the app can use `Form1.SomeProperty` instead of doing an OpenForms lookup on 'Form1' to get the instance. (it's irritating that you can't do Application.OpenForms.Where) In retrospect, a poor practice.